# Unable to Read Synapse LakeDB tables from PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, azure-synapse, apache-synapse, dynamic365

I have exported D365FnO tables using synapse links and when I try to read them within synapse studio I find no issues. But when I try to connect to lake db server through powerbi with same AD user, it's throwing me below error. It's saying either datafile does not exist or I do not have permission.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK9FC.png)

But when try to connect to same through excel it did work. Any idea what can be causing this behaviour?

I tried reading the same tables through excel and it did work. But my goal is access these tables from powerbi.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by re-installing the PowerBI through the official site instead of through Microsoft store and it worked.